# Setting up Community Events

Tags: discussion, community-event, community-guidelines

I have an event coming up for the community. I would like to post this on the Sitecore Stack Exchange site and have it featured somewhere so that the community get to know about the event while browsing the site. How can I set that up?

Comment: The disposition and accommodation for these types of posts/activities is currently under consideration and will be resolved in the upcoming weeks.

Comment: This has now been resolved.

Answer (score 9):

## What is a Community Event?

Community events are notices that will appear in the Sitecore Stack Exchange community bulletin. Currently, **only** the following events will be considered as community events for this bulletin. If you feel an event that is not on this list should be included, please post a comment here.

### Community Events

- Sitecore Hackathon
- Sitecore Unofficial Training Webinars
- Sitecore User Group events
- SUGCON

Things *not* considered for Community Events.

- Launch- and training-events for commercial tools (TDS, Coveo, etc.)
- Sitecore Symposium

## What is the Community Bulletin?

The Community Bulletin appears on the site when it has content. The rules for its content are as follows:

- If there is a community moderator **election**, [a link to it appears in the bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111673/create-a-permanent-link-to-the-electionarea-during-electiontime/132331#132331).
- **Events** can be created with a start date and time, an end date and time, a simple title, and a link to something somewhere on the network. Current or upcoming events are listed, with those starting or ending nearest to the current time shown first.
- If there are fewer than 4 events, **blog posts** from either [the Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) or [the site's blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/) are added to the list. A maximum of two posts will be shown, and only those posted in the past three days.
- If there are still fewer than 4 items listed, then **[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) meta posts** are shown (only those scoring 0 or above).
- If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions** not marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), scoring at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks. These are picked semi-randomly. At least *one* of these will always be added to the list, even if it pushes the length over 4. (Note that the timing and tags [can be adjusted per-site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268576/why-do-feature-requests-and-support-questions-appear-in-the-community-bulletin/268577#268577) to suit the needs of each community)

The URLs are checked at each stage to prevent [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131390/dont-show-meta-posts-that-are-also-linked-as-community-bulletins) items from being displayed (so that, for instance, a hot discussion post with the featured tag linked to a scheduled event won't ever fill 3 of the 4 slots).

**Additionally**, up to 2 recent (post created in the past two weeks) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts from **Meta Stack Exchange** will appear in the community bulletins of *all* sites. These are also labeled "meta". Note that these will appear in addition to all of the other stuff listed above, so the list of community bulletin posts might appear longer than usual, depending on the individual site circumstances.

[Source for rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130621/how-are-the-contents-of-the-community-bulletin-determined)

## How can I add my event?

Add a post to the https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com/ site and make sure it is tagged with the **[community-event](/questions/tagged/community-event)** tag. This will let the mods know that an event should be added to the list.

Make sure that you include all relevant information including:

- Date/Time (local)
- Date/Time (UTC) (important, the Community Bulletin runs on UTC)
- Location (if applicable)
- Links to event details
- Who to contact for information
- A description of the event

Once this has been picked up by a mod, it will be added to the SSE Community Event list and sometime before the event starts will appear in the bulletin.

Comment: One thing. Please do also include the date/time in UTC (still makes sense to list the event in local time as well). But the Community Bulletin is global and accepts only UTC.